# 3G dongle/hotspot that will support a VPN connection

Tags: vpn, 3g, dongle

I'm looking for a 3G solution for when I'm on the road for work.  I work in a mac shop, and being a developer, I need to connect to our VPNs (PPTP and L2TP).  I can't seem to find a 3G dongle/hotspot that will support a VPN connection on a mac.

Vendors I've looked at:

- Clear
- T-Mobile
- Verizon

And they all tell me that their 3G equipment will not work with a VPN.  Currently I am using a pay-as-you-go 3G dongle from Virgin Mobile, manufactured by Novatel (model MC760).  According to their user manual, the device supports VPN connections, but only for Windows.

Has anyone else had success implementing up a 3G/4G wireless solution that can connect to a VPN on their macs?

Comment: Around here, most home-style wireless 3G accounts don't allow VPN (due to the way they are dynamically splitting up the addressing between devices).  If you need VPN then you have to sign up for a business account, which costs bit more, but it gives you a static link, which should allow VPN.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the Novatel MiFi will do what you require.  Wonderful device.

http://www.anandtech.com/show/4500/novatel-wireless-mifi-4510l-review-the-best-4g-lte-wifi-hotspot

Available in 4G on both Sprint and Verizon.

Virgin Mobile also has one I believe (uses the sprint network), but I think they throttle the speeds.  Not entirely sure.

Comment: Yeah, Virgin Mobile will throttle speeds after 2.5GB